# Проблема с бэкграунд имедж

Tags: html, css, изображения

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CXOn.png
Проблема такова: У меня есть image с разрешением 5760х3840. 
в css на bg установлен bg-position: bottom center, bg-size: cover. ( без них никак ). Но вся соль в том, что мне нужно подвинуть это изображение еще чуть-чуть вправо . Это возможно реализовать ?Все перепробовал

Comment: padding-left: 10px; ?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-POSITION

Comment: Там нет ответа на мой вопрос

Comment: padding-left для bg-image?

Comment: укажите background-position:; не в top bottom а в % или в px

Comment: решил вопрос другим способом. Спасибо Всем